# Matching the pattern representing regexp set

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This question is not related to variable length look-behind as it probably has a solution without negative look-behind.

In Python3, I am trying to match a pattern that is probably at the limit of what can be achieved with a regexp, but I still want to give it a try. I am actually trying to avoid using a parsing tool.

What I want to match is the pattern that indicate a regexp set. So the following would be matched.

```
[abc]
[1-9\n\t]
[ \t\]]
[\\\]]
[[\\\\\\\]]
```

The square brackets cannot be nested, by example in `[[]]`, we want to match `[[]`.

Although, since a `\]` indicate an escaped bracket, we need to skip those. But a pattern such as `\\]` must be accepted. The following would not be matched.

```
[\]
[\\\]
[abc\\\]
```

The rule ends up being match from `[` to the first `]` that is not preceded by an odd amount of `\`.

It seems negative lookbehind does not work because it must have fixed length.

**Edit**: An interesting solution was given by Wiktor Stribiżew

```
re.compile(r'\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*)*\]')
```

**Edit**: Simpler version of the above by Rawing

```
r'\[(?:\\.|[^]\\])*\]'
```

Comment: Thank you, I am although trying to apply this to this specific problem.

Comment: What is the pattern you tried?

Comment: I found a pattern that seems to work, see answer below.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/nmYOPJ/1/. The question has nothing to do with variable width lookbehind. Although, there may be edge cases, but then you may use https://regex101.com/r/nmYOPJ/2.

Comment: Why are people closing this question. It took 10 minutes for us to realize it has nothing to do with lookbehind.

Comment: It is closed because you have not described the way to solve the issue in the question and made it unclear. Please edit the question to include the attempt at a working pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: A (in my opinion) more readable version of Wiktor's regex: `\[(?:\\.|[^]\\])*\]`

Comment: Thanks, those regexp solve my issue!

Comment: `\[(?:\\.|[^]\\])*\]` is "readable" but is much less efficient because it is not written with the unroll-the-loop principle in mind. `\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*)*\]`, depending on the input, may be 10 times as fast. Regex should be as efficient as it can, otherwise, your "readable" version may cause slowdowns or even crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.compile(r'\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*)*]', re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nmYOPJ/1).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^]\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `\`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching a sequence of:

  - `\\.` - a `\` char followed with any char
  - `[^]\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `\`
- `)*` - zero or more repetitions of the patterns inside the non-capturing group
- `]` - a `]` char.

The regex follows the [unroll-the-loop principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop). Depending on the input it may work much, even 10+ times faster than the non-unrolled version, [`r'\[(?:\\.|[^]\\])*]'`](https://regex101.com/r/nmYOPJ/4), that is based on an infinitely quantified alternation group, causing lots of redundant backtracking steps.

Note that the regex above can fail when the initial `[` is preceded with a backslash. In those cases, you will need

```
r'(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*(\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*)*])'
```

See this regex demo

The main difference here is `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*`, a `(?<!\\)` negative lookbehind that fails the match if the current position is preceded with a `\` char, and `(?:\\{2})*` that matches 0+ repetitions of two literal backslashes. The rest of the pattern is enclosed with capturing parentheses, and when a match is found, you just need to access `match.group(1)` to get the right value.